Quadratic form of fermion operators
In my lecture we were introduced with the 2nd quantization. We had a brief overview about it.
One thing that I couldn't understand was the change that takes place for the Hamiltonian as we consider different basis kets.
If, for when we consider single particle states of the form $|\nu\rangle$ with the corresponding creation operator $c^\dagger_\nu$, one can write the Hamitonian in the quadratic form of fermion operators:
$H=\sum_{\mu,\nu=1}^n h_{\mu,\nu}c^\dagger_{\mu}c_{\nu}$
with $h_{\mu,\nu}=\langle \mu|H|\nu\rangle$.
This expression comes as a surprise to me. The expression of the Hamiltonian as a linear combination of what is essentially number operators of different states, multiplied with coef. that is just the matrix element of the Hamiltonian between two considered states.
But I am willing to overlook this for the moment. What confused me was the following:
Considering $\gamma^\dagger_\alpha$ to be the creation operators for the orthonormal eigenstates $|\alpha\rangle$, the Hamiltonian (can) change form to:
$$H=\sum_{\alpha=1}^nE_\alpha\gamma^\dagger_\alpha\gamma_\alpha $$
with $E_\alpha$ being the eigenvalue of the eigenstate $|\alpha\rangle$ and $[H,\gamma^\dagger_\alpha]=E_\alpha\gamma^\dagger_\alpha$.
So my question is, why and how does this change in H happens?
I though that $\nu$ encompasses all the possible eigenstates of the system. And if $|\nu\rangle$ and $|\alpha\rangle$ are both eigenstates, and both have ladder operators, why would the Hamiltonian change? Is there somehow a finer categorizing or splitting of the eigenstates, that I am not aware of?
Edit:
It is also written that $\gamma^\dagger_\alpha=\sum_{\nu=1}^n a_\nu c^\dagger_\nu $.
So we are expressing one type of ladder operator as a linear combination of some other. Which implies that some sort of distinction between operators, that encapsulate/represent a vast number of basis kets can be made


I though that ν
encompasses all the possible eigenstates of the system.

As you wrote the equation for $\nu$ state, it is not necessarily an eigenstate of the system. If it was, we should have
$$
h_{\mu,\nu} = E_\nu \delta_{\mu,\nu}
$$
and we would recover the same equation you wrote for $\alpha$ states.

Considering $\gamma^\dagger_\alpha$
to be the creation operators for the orthonormal eigenstates $|\alpha\rangle$
, the Hamiltonian (can) change...

If this states are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, it not only can but for sure will change to diagonal form, by definition.

why and how does this change in H happens?

This is just a basis change, like in linear algebra. Everything we do with vectors in vector algebra can be translated in operator algebra here.
